# filter a view with date

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, sql-view

I have made a view in order to analyze a specific subject with PowerBI(I can't use other program). In My case the dataBase is according to the following ERD:
[The ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Af84.png)

I've created the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW sales_based_foodstyless AS 
            ( 
                     SELECT   food_style, 
                              total_quantities=Sum(quantity), 
                              average_dish_price=Avg(d.price), 
                              total _revenue=sum(quantity*price), 
                              orders_amount=count(DISTINCT o.orderid), 
                              total_vendors_operating=count( v.vendorid) 
                     FROM     vendors  AS v 
                     JOIN     food_style AS fs 
                     ON       fs.vendorid=v.vendorid 
                     JOIN     dishes AS d 
                     ON       v.vendorid=d.vendorid 
                     JOIN     dish_quantities AS dq 
                     ON       d.vendorid=dq.vendorid 
                     JOIN     orders AS o 
                     ON       dq.orderid=o.orderid 
                     GROUP BY food_style 
            )
```

I want in the PowerBI to filter the data by date which is to be found as Order_Date of the joined table in the select statement of the view. however I cannot managed to do it.
Help Please

Comment: Can't you just add Order_Date to the select?

Comment: @M.Kanarkowski -- he is doing a group by

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter for example

```
  CREATE VIEW sales_based_foodstyless AS 
  ( 
    SELECT  
      food_style, 
      total_quantities=Sum(quantity), 
      average_dish_price=Avg(d.price), 
      total _revenue=sum(quantity*price), 
      orders_amount=count(DISTINCT o.orderid), 
      total_vendors_operating=count( v.vendorid) 
    FROM vendors  AS v 
    JOIN food_style AS fs      ON fs.vendorid=v.vendorid 
    JOIN dishes AS d           ON v.vendorid=d.vendorid 
    JOIN dish_quantities AS dq ON d.vendorid=dq.vendorid 
    JOIN orders AS o           ON dq.orderid=o.orderid 
    WHERE YEAR(order_date) = 2018
    GROUP BY food_style 
  )
```

However, if you want to do this dynamically you would have to use a stored procedure or parameterized view.

Comment: I want to this dynamically in the PowerBI. choosing year intervals with a filter inside the powerBI.what code should I add in SQL Server or PowerBI so I'll be able to make it happen?

Comment: @yon1000 - you can't do it if the group by is part of the view -- you can only filter on elements that are in a column

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fSelectSalesBasedFoodstyles (
    @StartDate DATE
    , @EndDate DATE
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN

    SELECT   food_style, 
            total_quantities=Sum(quantity), 
            average_dish_price=Avg(d.price), 
            total _revenue=sum(quantity*price), 
            orders_amount=count(DISTINCT o.orderid), 
            total_vendors_operating=count( v.vendorid) ,
            order_date
    FROM     vendors  AS v 
    JOIN     food_style AS fs 
    ON       fs.vendorid=v.vendorid 
    JOIN     dishes AS d 
    ON       v.vendorid=d.vendorid 
    JOIN     dish_quantities AS dq 
    ON       d.vendorid=dq.vendorid 
    JOIN     orders AS o 
    ON       dq.orderid=o.orderid 
        -- CAST only necessary if OrderDate is a DATETIME:
    WHERE CAST(o.order_date AS DATE) >= @StartDate 
        AND CAST(o.order_date AS DATE) <= @EndDate
    GROUP BY food_style 

GO
```